# StackPlonk: plonk users you don't want to help anymore

Tags: script, users

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: Plonk button in profile page]

[image: Warning message on a question from a plonked user]

### About

If you really don't want to help some user anymore, go to his profile page, and click the *Plonk* button next to his name. Every question of this user will then have a big warning *Don't answer: this user is plonked*.

You may always unplonk the user by clicking the *Unplonk* button next to his name, in his profile page.

The plonk list is saved in Firefox `about:config` page. Search for "plonk" to find it.

#### License

No license. Do whatever you want with it.

#### Download

[Download from <strike>userscripts.org</strike> userscripts-mirror.org](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/122583)

#### Platform

Firefox, or any browser supporting Greasemonkey scripts.